# Why is contextlib not installed by virtualenv?

Tags: python

This:

```
$ virtualenv --always-copy myvenv
```

Is not copying `contextlib.py` (amongst other modules) from the stdlib. It is copying other modules.

Why?

How can I tell virtualenv to create a fully self-contained virutal environment, including:

- the full standard libraries
- all python tools (python itself, virtualenv, pip, ...)
- all shared libraries

The rationale behind this is that I am creating a virtualenv using a global python custom installation which gets removed as soon as the virtualenv is created.

Comment: I don't think that virtualenv is supposed to work that way. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: if you want you can manually copy it to that folder.

Comment: @FlyingTeller as said, because the global python installation is just used to bootstrap the virtualenv, and then it gets removed. Actually, I would ask the question in the other direction: why is virtualenv assuming that there is a global python installation which will be there during runtime, when the goal of virtualenv is (should be) to create fully self-contained installations? I understand that this could be an optimization flag (to save disk space, meh!?), but this makes the virtualenv brittle: any change in the global python installation affects all virtualenvs created with that version

Comment: @JainilPatel I will, but what can I copy? Everything in the standard lib? Including directories? Why is there no flag to tell virtualenv to do this? Even worse, virtualenv creates links for each module in the standard lib from the venv to the global installation when running without flags, but when running with `--always-copy` it copies *some* standard modules, but not all. Why? How are the modules to be copied selected?

Comment: virtual env is nothing but just a different folder with python installed, just copy the packages from lib, sitepackages to another location manually.